# Using Shopify Liquid I want to get the product object from blocks

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want to get the product object from the blocks setting, but it only seems to return the handle. Is there any way to get the entire product object without naming each one specifically.

The code below works for collections, but not blocks.

```
{%- liquid
  assign ss = section.settings
  assign collection = collections[ss.based_on_collection]

-%}
{% assign productsArray = "" %}

{% if ss.carousel_type == 'manual' %}
  {% for block in section.blocks %}
    {% assign productJSON = block.settings.product | json %}
    {% if productsArray == "" %}
      {% assign productsArray = productJSON %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign productsArray = productsArray | append: "," | append: productJSON %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% elsif ss.carousel_type == 'collection' %}
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    {% assign productJSON = product | json %}
    {% if productsArray == "" %}
      {% assign productsArray = productJSON %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign productsArray = productsArray | append: "," | append: productJSON %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% assign productsArray = "[" | append: productsArray | append: "]" %}
```

I am able to get to work using all_products like this. but this is taxing and I wanted to avoid using it. I could also use the Storefront API inside of a JavaScript file, but I was trying to do this only using liquid. Is it possible?

```
{% assign productHandle = block.settings.product %}
{% assign product = all_products[productHandle] %}
```

Comment: No, you can't do the same using liquid code, liquid allow product details using `all_products` object only.

Answer (score 0):

the product option on a section schema only returns the handle, if you want the entire object do something like:

```
  {% for block in section.blocks %}
    {% assign product = all_products[block.settings.product] %}
    <a href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```